# Match a string that contains a dot

Tags: python

I'm trying to find some words in a text file and replace them.
I've stored in variables the words to be replaced. For example:

```
COR00g1.1   SolycCB00g000010
```

So, in the text I need to find "`COR00g1.1`" word and replace with "`SolycCB00g000010`". The problem is that "COR00g1.1" is actually matching another words.
Example:

Input:

```
ch00    assembler   exon    1146259 1146582 .   -   .   ID=exon2;Parent=COR00g1.1.2,COR00g1.1.3

ch00    assembler   transcript  4197578 4197801 .   +   .   Parent=COR00g131.1;ID=COR00g131.1.1;official=no
```

Output:

```
ch00 assembler  exon    1146259 1146582 .   -   .   ID=exon2;Parent=SolycCB00g000010.2,SolycCB00g000010.3

ch00 assembler  transcript  4197578 4197801 .   +   . Parent=SolycCB00g000010.1;ID=SolycCB00g000010.1.1;official=no
```

As can be observed, the second line is also replaced with the new ID while it shouldn't.

This is the code I'm using:

```
with open(fname, "r") as dataf:
    reader = csv.reader(dataf, delimiter="\t")
    for line in reader:
        line[8] = re.sub(search, replace, line[8])
```

Comment: Sorry if it is not enough clear. search is "COR00g1.1" (in this case) and replace "SolycCB00g000010".

Comment: You haven't shown your full code, but note that `.` is a special character in regular expressions (it matches any single character). Thus, the regex `"1.1"` will match all of `"1.1"`, `"131"`, `"1x1"`, etc. If you just want a substring search, use that instead of regular expressions. If you do continue using regexps, you need to understand what all the special characters do. There are online tools like [this](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl) that may help.

Comment: Why don't you just say `line[8] = line[8].replace("COR00g1.1", "SolycCB00g000010"")`?  Why use a regular expression if there is only one sequence of characters that will match?

Comment: As @Useless said, you likely need to use a \ character to escape the . in your regex

Comment: Yes, I know the problem, but I do not know how to avoid it

Comment: Please add the `search` and `replace` variable declarations, because `search` needs to be changed.

Comment: To avoid it, use `r"COR00g1\.1"` or just use normal string replacement.

Comment: Without seeing your code it's impossible to know but it looks like you're failing to escape the '.' (you should be using '\.')

Comment: I'm not using line[8] = line[8].replace("COR00g1.1", "SolycCB00g000010"") because I have a list of words to be replaced, and I'm calling a function to replace them two by two ("search" and "replace". So maybe I need to check if "search" has a dot, and if it is true, add a "\" just before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know the problem, but I do not know how to avoid it

You're looking for a defined substring rather than a pattern, so just don't use regular expressions in the first place.

Simple substring replacement would look like:

```
line[8] = line[8].replace('COR00g1.1', 'SolycCB00g000010')
```

If you must use regular expressions, you need to escape the `.` so it's treated as a literal character: eg.

```
search = 'COR00g1\.1'
```

---

Edit: to address this comment:

> I have a list of words to be replaced, and I'm calling a function to replace them two by two

doesn't mean you need to use regular expressions, it just means you need to use variables. For example:

```
def searchAndReplace(search, replace):
    # your code here
    line[8] = line[8].replace(search, replace)
```

Passing a literal string where a regex is expected, and then munging that string to hopefully escape all special regex characters is the worst of all worlds.

There's no benefit to using regular expressions if you only want simple substring matching, and you've added significant complexity. To paraphrase the well-known [Jamie Zawinski quote](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247), you've created an extra problem without *any* benefit.